# Create installer for multiple applications

Tags: c#, windows-installer, expression-encoder

Good day. I am trying to create an installer for a C# application. The C# application is only one file with two empty directories (videos, photos) . For the application to function correctly, it is necessary to have Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 installed. So installer must install C# application at first and then Microsoft Expression Encoder 4. Can someone advice to me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need a bootstrapper / chainer.   Take a look at Windows Installer XML or InstallShield.  They each have patterns for creating an MSI and wrapping it up into an EXE embedded with other MSI/EXE to all be installed together.